# Adding a Spring event listener to the Camunda BPM Run Docker

Tags: java, spring-boot, camunda

I'd like to do some work triggered by Camunda process instance state changes and as such have written a Spring annotation-driven event listener for Camunda.

I've packaged it into a JAR file: code and `pom.xml` are on Gist [here](https://gist.github.com/helgridly/5e62139852ca328c9df520752049efeb).

I've written a Dockerfile that extends `camunda/camunda-bpm-platform:run-7.14.0` and am poking the resulting JAR into `/camunda/configuration/userlib`.

This is definitely in the Spring boot loader path, according to `ps`:

```
10 camunda   0:31 java -Dloader.path=/camunda/internal/webapps/,/camunda/internal/rest/,/camunda/configuration/userlib/,/camunda/configuration/keystore/ -Dcamunda.deploymentDir=/camunda/configuration/resources -jar /camunda/internal/camunda-bpm-run-core.jar --spring.config.location=file:/camunda/configuration/default.yml
```

Inspecting the log, Camunda is definitely firing up Spring eventing:

```
o.c.b.s.b.s.event.EventPublisherPlugin   : EVENTING-001: Initialized Camunda Spring Boot Eventing Engine Plugin.
o.c.b.s.b.s.event.EventPublisherPlugin   : EVENTING-003: Task events will be published as Spring Events.
o.c.b.s.b.s.event.EventPublisherPlugin   : EVENTING-005: Execution events will be published as Spring Events.
o.c.b.s.b.s.event.EventPublisherPlugin   : EVENTING-007: History events will be published as Spring events.
```

But I am seeing none of my log messages.

This leads me to suspect that simply dropping a JAR on the loader isn't quite enough for Spring Boot to find the listener - but I don't know what else I'm missing.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Related SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63933392/hook-events-from-camunda-usertask), which points to example code [here](https://github.com/camunda-consulting/code/tree/master/snippets/spring-event-bridge). I've hewn pretty close to that example, to no avail.

If this isn't a breach of SO etiquette, I suspect that @rob2universe might be able to help here.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I realised what I was doing wrong here. I was under the mistaken assumption that any JAR files on the classpath would automatically have their classes initialised, which would in turn mean Spring would notice the `@Component` and `@EventListener` annotations and then... Do Some Magic to add the listener. This is not true.

I now understand that the right thing to do is to use the Camunda Initializr to build an entirely *new* Spring Boot application that includes my listener and then roll a Docker around that. So that's my path forward now.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to make sure that any Spring components you declare fall under the configured **Spring component scan** @see e.g. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-component-scanning

In your case this probably only means that you need to adjust the package name to be a sub-package of the package of the Application class. Alternatively you can add configuration to extend the Spring component scan to your packages.